# How can I get last 3 term?

Tags: c#, mouse, coordinate

I want to get last 3 X and Y coordinates from using mouse move on the form( or picturebox).It should renew whenever I click (right click better) the screen.
How can get last 3 coordinates?

I got coordinates with;

```
int Xcoordinate, Ycoordinate;

Xcoordinate = Cursor.Position.X;
Ycoordinate = Cursor.Position.Y;

label1.Text=Xcoordinate.ToSring();
```

or

```
listBox.Items.Add(Xcoordinate);
```

Actually I dont know I get last item, penultimate one and last but one item with using C#.
Secondly is it possible to get last 3 coordinates without using listbox or any like toolbox item just writing a method/function.

Regards

Comment: If I got your question correctly, you need to add them into some list or array

Comment: You get one position at a time, if you want to get an history you should probably store it in a queue or a list.

Comment: I will try 

    string[] items = GetAllItems();

    string lastItem = items[items.Length - 1];

    string lastItem2 = items[items.Length - 2];   //I can not write comment to my questions. ?!%

Comment: Why an array of String?

Comment: It will give an idea to get last term and last-1 (If we use listbox1). I will try for int array. Then if it is possible (for ex: X=15, Y=35 which is coordinate1) I will define coordinate1 to get X and Y coordinates. When comparing u and me, I am dummy in C# :)

Comment: Check my answer, if you want to take at least one thing from my answer  please use Vector2.

Comment: I got carried away and wrote the code for you. Enjoy, I don't do this often.

Answer (score 0):

Add them into a [**Stack**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx). Then you can grab the last three elements from the stack by popping the last three elements out of the stack.

I recommend the stack instead of the queue because you only care about the last three instead of the first three.

Use a [**Vector2**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2_members.aspx) Stack to store x and y coordinates.

```
private Stack<Vector2> history;

public Vector2[] GetLastThree()
{
    Vector2 [] array = new Vector2[3];
    array[0] = history.pop();
    array[1] = history.pop();
    array[2] = history.pop();

    return array;
}
```

---

Another way to solve the problem, I prefer this one. This one you manage the array yourself. I think of it as a stack of 3 elements.

```
public CoordinateManager
{
        // Create an array of three elements. Initalize all to 0,0.
    private Vector2[] list = {Vector2.Zero, Vector2.Zero, Vector2.Zero};

    public void storeCoordinate(Vector2 coord)
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)  
          list[i] = list[i+1];

        list[i] = coord;
    }

    public void getLastThree()
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask some question about above codes? After adding CoordinateManager class, I have error at Vector.Zero . sorry for taking your time. But anyway thanks for patience and replies

Comment: I had a mistake in the code, try it now. Also make sure you import `System.Windows`.

Comment: @ceng If your question has been answered, please accept the answer so that others can know the problem has been solved.